# Make button globally unclickable

Tags: php, button

I want to know if there is a way to implement a button in php, which gets disabled when a user clicks it, so nobody else can click it for an hour. I mean that if another user comes to the site, he sees that the button was clicked, and he cannot click it.

Comment: Please show us your code....!

Comment: yes, there are lot of ways.

Comment: use mysql to store the button state along with the click time.

Comment: Can you please change the title so that it is a question?

Comment: please you have to show us your code that you're  trying..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code flow should be something like:

Button clicked for the first time ?
insert in MySql the `button id` and `click time`

---

Next time a user comes to that page ?
Query mysql and check if the button was click less than 1 hour ago, if so, `disable the button`, otherwise `enable it`.

---

To disable a button you can use:

```
<button type="button" disabled>Cannot Click Me!</button>
```

To enable it, just remove `disabled`:

```
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. hi, to your question, what i think you should do is store a table in your database that checks for if button was clicked, and store in the database(use insert query) use {datetime should be a column }(database)
2. On the button use a just do a

   >button

3.use a server cron job that will check and update your database every 1 hour.

Comment: why do you need a cron job ?

Comment: to check your database and update it so that php would not echo disable     button area use <button type="button" <?php if($row["clicked"] == "clicked" ) { echo " disabled"; } ?> >Cannot Click Me!</button>

Comment: You don't need a cron job, just a mysql query.

Comment: A cron job makes a check every hour and updates the mysql query to unclicked or what ever you are using. i have don it before...

Comment: Absolutely nonsense.